# function for substituting and adding columns in dataset out of an underlying "lexicon"

Tags: r, function, loops, dataset, substitution

I have an underlying dataset of soldier´s heights (N = 150,000) with the following columns of interest:

height, bplace (city), bregion (county)

with 5,000 distinct observations for bregion and 75,000 distinct observations for bplace.

```
data_original <- data.frame(
                     "bplace"=c("Paris", "Mannheim","Munich","Augsburg"), 
                     "bregion"=c("Holland", "Baden", "Baviro", "Bavaria"), 
                     "heightcm" = c("170.5", "167.0", "171.3", "175.4"),
                     "lattitude" = 1:4
                     "longitude" = 1:4
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

View(data_original)
```

As you can see in this underlying example, the birth region for Paris and Munich is incorrect and needs to be corrected.

**My goal is to assign the correct geocraphical coordinates (lattitude, longitude) to the specific regions, so every bplace within a bregion has the same geo-coordinates.**

Because the dataset contains observations from 17th/18th century, all of the regions had to be recoded by hand.
Therefore I created a "lexicon", containing the original bregions, their matches (which I assigned manually) and their lattitude and longitude.

The lexicon does look something similiar to this:

```
lexicon <- data.frame("bregion"=c("Holland", "Baden", "Baviro","Bavaria"),
                     "bregion_matches" = c("Ile-de-France", "Baden", "Bavaria","Bavaria"),
                     "lattitude" = c("47.5", "50.2", "46.1", "40.2"),
                     "longitude" = c("0.3", "-1.2", "2.1", "7.8"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) 

View(lexicon)
```

Now I want to substitute every bregion_original within the original dataset with their corresponding bregion_matches, matches_lattitude and matches_longitude.

Therefore I need to create a function, which runs through all of my 150,000 observations and substitutes the bregions_original with their bregion_matches, matches_lattitude and matches_longitude.

My final dataframe should look like this:

```
data_matched <- data.frame(
                     "bplace"=c("Paris", "Mannheim","Munich","Augsburg"), 
                     "bregion_matched"=c("Ile-de-France", "Baden", "Bavaria", "Bavaria"), 
                     "lattitude" = c("47.5", "50.2", "46.1", "40.2"),
                     "longitude" = c("0.3", "-1.2", "2.1", "7.8"),
                     "heightcm" = c("170.5", "167.0", "171.3", "175.4"), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

View(data_matched)
```

The problem is that i can´t use a simple merge function, because I just have every distinct (~5000) regions within my lexicon listed, not all of the 150,000 observed regions.

This should be the logic behind the substitutions, but of course this code is no sufficient solution.

```
for(bregion in data_original){
    if (data_original$bregion == lexicon$bregion){
    substitute(data_original$bregion, by lexicon$bregion_matched){
    substitute(data_original$lattitude, by lexicon$lattitude){
    substitute(data_original$longitude, by lexicon$longitude)
}}}}
```

Does anyone has a guess how I can solve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide a small subset of your data and the expected output.  Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: This sounds like a `merge` (or join) operation. Given sample data, I think the resolution will be direct.

Comment: I just edited the former post and added some example coding

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `lexicon` object as a list, it would be simple to do something like the following.

```r
lexicon <- list(
  "Holland" = list(
    "bregion_match" = "Ile-de-France",
    "lattitude" = "47.5",
    "longitude" = "0.3"
    ),
  "Baden" = list(
    "bregion_match" = "Baden",
    "lattitude" = "50.2",
    "longitude" = "-1.2"
  ),
  "Baviro" = list(
    "bregion_match" = "Bavaria",
    "lattitude" = "46.1",
    "longitude" = "2.1"
  ),
  "Bavaria" = list(
    "bregion_match" = "Bavaria",
    "lattitude" = "40.2",
    "longitude" = "7.8"
  )
)

for (bregion in data_original$bregion) {
  replacement = lexicon[[bregion]]
  matching_rows = data_original$bregion == bregion
  data_original[matching_rows , "bregion_matched"] = replacement[["bregion_match"]]
  data_original[matching_rows , "lattitude"] = replacement[["lattitude"]]
  data_original[matching_rows , "longitude"] = replacement[["longitude"]]
  
}
```

If you can't have lexicon as a list like that, the same idea applies, but you have to make sure the replacement is of length 1 so it is recycled to the appropriate length when replacing. Let me know if you need help with the data frame approach if you can't have `lexicon` as a list.

**EDIT**

Given that every row is unique in `lexicon` in terms of the "bregion", you can do

```r
lexicon <- data.frame(
  "bregion"=c("Holland", "Baden", "Baviro","Bavaria"),
  "bregion_matches" = c("Ile-de-France", "Baden", "Bavaria","Bavaria"),
  "lattitude" = c("47.5", "50.2", "46.1", "40.2"),
  "longitude" = c("0.3", "-1.2", "2.1", "7.8"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) 

lexicon_list = vector("list", nrow(lexicon))

for (i in 1:nrow(lexicon)) {
  bregion = lexicon[i, ]
  lexicon_list[[i]] = list(
    "bregion_match" = lexicon[[i, "bregion_matches"]],
    "lattitude" = lexicon[[i, "lattitude"]],
    "longitude" = lexicon[[i, "longitude"]]
  )
}

names(lexicon_list) = lexicon$bregion
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems to be very helpful, but I´m wondering if I need to transform every of the 5,000 original bregions as a "list" object manually?